# Joomla Session Variable is not stored

Tags: session, joomla1.5

I am working with Joomla. 
On one page i am setting some session variable by following code.

```
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
$session->set( 'myvar', 'helloworld','my_shop' );
```

and then my site redirects to another page. but i am not able to get that variable in secode page by following.

```
echo 'Session variable myvar has value: ' . $session->get( 'myvar', 'empty' );
```

I am using  $mainframe->redirect() in controller.Just before redirection i am getting session variable and just after redirection i am not getting session variable.

Also session having other variables (previously stored) while redirecting but they are preserved!!!...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add $session =& JFactory::getSession(); on the second page?

Answer (score 0):

So the official answer is:

Add

> $session =& JFactory::getSession();

on the second page before calling $session->get()

Comment: Sorry too, but what error are you getting? How does your code look like?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still learning about Joomla sessions, but to me it looks like you are using a different namespace when trying to get the session.

The name space used to set the session is called `my_shop`.

```
$session->set( 'myvar', 'helloworld','my_shop' );
```

The namespace used to get the session is called `empty`.

```
$session->get( 'myvar', 'empty' );
```